# Highcharts SVG Export from Python Server Side Code

Tags: python, django, graph, reportlab, highcharts

I am using [reportlab](https://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) in python to render a pdf server side.

I really like the look of [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) graphs.  But I am building a pdf server side which needs to include some graphs.  The server side graphing ([reportlab](https://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)) do not have nearly as much choices for formatting / design.

Is there a way I can run a client side javascript graphing solution ([highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com)) from the server side?

Here is a [post](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6172) with that request and this is what they said: 
You feed this Java tool a URL, it fires up its internal WebKit browser, executes the JavaScript code and dumps the rendered page to PDF.

I am looking for resources on how this could be accomplished in python.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Open a web browser on the server.
2. Point the web browser at a pre-made page that loads `highcharts` and renders your chart.
3. Grab the output of the browser.
4. Send that to a client.

Which of those steps seems confusing?

Note that this will be significantly slower than just using `matplotlib`, because you need to start up a full web browser just to render a graph. I had a quick look at the highcharts page you linked and I think you could probably reproduce that in matplotlib.

Comment: I will see about reproducing that in matplotlib.

Comment: P.S. specifically which step seemed confusing #2.  I have not ran a browser from the server, rendered content and saved it locally before.

Comment: It should be the same as doing it locally, depending on the server. You could use something like `selenium` or even `pywin32` (on Windows, naturally) to open the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar requirements and couldn't find an existing solution so I created a little proof-of-concept solution [here](https://github.com/moredip/highcharts-in-python).

This implementation works by having the python process create a node subprocess that uses the `highchart-export-server` node module which in turn spawns a PhantomJS instance to render the chart. A few russian dolls involved there, but it does the job.